# How to make generic xsd which should validate only mandaotry fields

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I want to write an xsd which to pass the validation only for mandatory fields.

I have written below xsd for the xml.

```
<Order OrderNo="12345" OrgCode="US">
    <OrderLines>
        <OrderLine OrderLineNo="1" OrderLineKey="1" />
        <OrderLine OrderLineNo="2" OrderLineKey="2" />
    </OrderLines>
</Order>
```

In above xml OrderNo, OrgCode, OrderLineNo, OrderLineKey are mandatory fields.

I have written below xsd for above xml.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Order">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="OrderLines">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="OrderLine" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="OrderLineNo" use="required"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="OrderLineKey" use="required"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="OrderNo" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="OrgCode" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now I want below xml to validate against above xsd,  which has some additioanl attributes which are optional. As below:

```
<Order OrderNo="12345" OrgCode="US" Email="ab@gmail.com">
    <OrderLines>
        <OrderLine OrderLineNo="1" OrderLineKey="1"  Qty="2"/>
    </OrderLines>
</Order>
```

I want my xsd to written in a way which can allow any number of optional attributes (Email, Qty and any attribute which is not mandatory) and elements. Even if they are not defined in the xsd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xs:any](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_any.asp) element in the place you want to be able to add the unspecified elements to, and [xs:anyAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_anyattribute.asp) element in the place where you want the additional attributes.

To make your example validate, you would need to change it to

```xml
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Order">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="OrderLines">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="OrderLine" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="OrderLineNo" use="required"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="OrderLineKey" use="required"/>
                      <xs:anyAttribute/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="OrderNo" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="OrgCode" use="required"/>
      <xs:anyAttribute/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```